# Setter injection with hierarchical controls in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, dependency-injection, structuremap

Trying to inject dependencies to usercontrols in WinForms. As the instantiation of controls is generated by designer, only setter injection seems to be possible.
My objective is to directly reference DI container only at the form level:

```
public void Form(StructureMap.Container container)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   container.BuildUp(this); // this should also traverse Controls and their subcontrols
}
```

The problem is how to force DI container to traverse the Controls collection hierarchically and inject dependencies. Is this possible with any DI container? Trying with StructureMap and so far no luck:

```
Container container = new Container(delegate (ConfigurationExpression e)
{    
    InjectedClass c = new InjectedClass();

    e.Policies.SetAllProperties(delegate (StructureMap.Configuration.DSL.SetterConvention x) 
    {
        x.OfType<InjectedClass>();
    });             

    e.For<InjectedClass>().Use(c);

});

Form form1 = new Form(container);

// here the form.Controls[0].Controls[0].MyInjectedClass has no instance
```

StructureMap seems to stop at the first level (injecting to `Form.MyInjectedClass` is working)

Comment: It depends on how you set up your ui. If you are working with the designer you cannot dynamicly do that as the designer depends on instantiated controls. You would have to use the container to resolve your controls in the desinger file.

Comment: @Dr.Fre I'm willing to give up the constructor injection in favor of ability to edit controls from designer. I'm just expecting that DI container will traverse the entire object graph in the `BuildUp`.

Answer (score 0):

I Couldn't do it either.
I used structuremap with setter injection and called ObjectFactory.BuildUp in every control.

Define a CustomInjectAttribute

```
public class CustomInjectAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Define a Registry

```
public class MyRegistry : Registry
{
    public MyRegistry()
    {
         this.Policies.SetAllProperties(by => by.Matching(prop => prop.HasAttribute<CustomInjectAttribute>()));
    }
}
```

Then call BuildUp on Control's constructor:

```
    public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ObjectFactory.BuildUp(this);
    }

    [CustomInject, Browsable(false)]
    public IInjectable Injectable { protected get; set; }
}
```